# What is this yellow daisy-like flower?

Tags: identification, flowers

I don't know much about plants, but it does look like a different colored daisy.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These are called Marguerite Daisy.  An annual but if you allow a few to go to seed they will come back the next year.  I can't offer you a species[marguerite daisy](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7166/6571179981_779509ae69_z.jpg) but to keep these blooming the entire season you need to cut off the flowers.  At the end of the season leave a dozen flowers to go to seed.  By cutting off flowers and not allowing them to go to seed the entire plant gets more vigorous and produces flowers all the while trying to set seed.  The job of any annual is to set seed.  Once it has set seed the parent plant can go to daisy heaven so to speak.  Any annual can be made to last longer, the plant itself gets more vigorous and larger and produces copious flowers in an effort to set seed somehow.  That is their job.  Cutting flowers off even new ones is your task to have lots of flowers and a healthier flower bed.  Good luck trying to NOT allow some of the flowers to not go to seed!  Just remember when you allow those flowers to produce seed the plant will start to diminish and die.  Collect seed if you want but the seed is easily shaken from the dried up flower and into the soil to grow next season.  Internet is wimpy on these plants.  Some of the pictures under Marguerite are not Marguerite.  Especially those purple ones...

I actually use a hedging shear to cut off the flowers and make a more even massing of flowers...middle of summer? A rounded undulating mass of flowers. A little fertilizer where the nitrogen is less in percentage than the phosphorus and potassium.  Too much nitrogen will produce a lot of leaves and no flowers.